# A formula for operator $\frac D{e^D-1}$?

Tags: linear-transformations, finite-differences, formal-power-series

Is there a good unambiguous formula for the linear operator $\frac D{e^D-1}$?

I mean,

$$x^a\to B_a(x)$$
$$\ln x \to \psi(x)$$
$$e^x\to\frac{e^x}{e-1}$$

etc.

Comment: You mean the operator $D(e^D-1)^{-1}$?

Comment: @CameronWilliams yes

Comment: This is the derivative of the operator that gives the [Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/684942).

Comment: @robjohn yes, we first differentiate, then discrete integrate. The problem is, discrete integration is ambiguous (needs fixing constants etc). I need them fixed as in the examples above.

Comment: Except in rare instances, the series from this operator do not converge. This is why the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula usually provides asymptotic formulas rather than convergent ones.

Comment: The examples in your question seem to be $f(x)\to g(x)$ where $f'(x)=g(x+1)-g(x)$. However, note that $g(x)+C$ works just as well on the right hand side, so I don't think there will be an unambiguous operator that will not involve some constant that can be adjusted.

Comment: @robjohn I answered myself

Answer (score 0):

Seems, something like this:

$$\frac D{e^D-1}f(x)=\frac1{2 \pi }\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty } \frac{e^{-iwx}}{e^{-i w}-1}\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty } e^{i t w} f'(t) \, dt \, dw$$