# Philip Hall's theorem

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, combinatorial-proofs, algebraic-combinatorics

Here is the theorem I want to prove:

For $x,y \in P$ and $i \geq 0,$ let $c_i(x,y)$ be the number of chains $x=x_0 < x_1 < \dots < x_i = y$ of length $i$ from $x$ to $y.$ Let $$\phi (x,y) = c_0(x,y) - c_1(x,y) + c_2(x,y) - c_3(x,y) + \dots. $$
Prove that $\mu (x,y) = \phi (x,y).$

Where $\mu$s the Mobius Function and $P$ is a finite poset.

**My thoughts are:**

I found a proof for it in the following link here: [Phillip Hall's theorem on chains](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4132825/phillip-halls-theorem-on-chains) but my formula has chains of length zero, is always the number of chains of length zero is zero? What is an example of a chain of length zero?

How also I can proof the statement by induction, could anyone show me the details please?

Comment: I am totally unfamiliar with the subject matter that you are questioning, as well as the syntax used in your posting.  However, it seems as if the theorem is based on Inclusion-Exclusion; I could easily be wrong.  If it is based on Inclusion-Exclusion, then the following articles may be helpful to you: See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) for an 
introduction to Inclusion-Exclusion.
...see next comment

Comment: Then, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4427605/inclusion-exclusion-principle-what-is-1n1/4427645#4427645) for an explanation of and justification for the Inclusion-Exclusion *formula*.

Comment: how will this help me in the proof by induction? @user2661923

Comment: I don't know whether an Inclusion-Exclusion approach will be of any help in an Induction proof of the theorem that you are trying to prove.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So $\phi (x,y) = \displaystyle \sum _{i = 0}^{\infty}(-1)^ic_i(x,y),$ where clearly the sum is finite, because the poset is finite.

1. $\phi (x,x)=1$ :
   There is only one chain of size $0$ from $x$ to $x$, so $c_0(x,x)=1$ and $c_i(x,x)=0$ for $i>0$, hence $\phi (x,x)=1$.
2. $\phi (x,y) = \displaystyle -\sum _{x\leq z<y}\phi (x,z)$ :
   Using the definition on the RHS, we have that
   $$\displaystyle -\sum _{x\leq z<y}\phi (x,z) = \displaystyle -\sum _{x\leq z<y}\sum _{i = 0}^{\infty}(-1)^ic_i(x,z),$$ exchanging the sums (they are finite and independent), we have that $$RHS = \sum _{i = 0}^{\infty}(-1)^{i+1}\sum _{x\leq z<y}c_i(x,z),$$ so if we show that $c_{i+1}(x,y)=\displaystyle \sum _{x\leq z<y}c_i(x,z)$, we are done, but this is obvious from the definition as if you consider $x=x_0<\cdots <x_i=z<y$ this is a chain of size $i+1$.

Because $\mu$, the Möbius function, also respects this recursion and these initial conditions, they are the same function.